# How do I pipe the banner of an ssh login into a text file?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am running a script like so that invokes an SSH banner I created as well as invokes a script on a remote machine that creates a file and runs ls -la as a picture of this text capture shows:

[image]

However, the text capture did not have the banner inside it as well.  Rather the banner output on it's own and was never written to out.txt as seen below:

[image]

How do I make it such that the banner outputs to the text file as well?

Comment: Please use embedded text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to redirect STDERR to the file as well

```
bash ./assig4_2.sh > out.txt 2>&1
```